# What is the appropriate test to calculate p-value over time between two groups?

Tags: p-value, sas, biostatistics

I have two sample groups and they are paired and normalized each sample induction to the initial fold induction (at time = 0). As such, all samples at time = 0 should be 1 or 100%. I am looking to see the stability between the two groups over time. Which test would be appropriate in SAS to run to see the p-value over time?

Comment: How many times has each individual been measured?

Answer (score 1):

More details of your experimental / analytical design might suggest another answer here, but it sounds like you're looking for a t-test?  In which case it's proc ttest for SAS.  Here's a basic usage example; see link below for documentation on paired design.

```
ods graphics on; 

proc ttest
    data = your_data; 
    class your_group_classification_variable; 
    var your_var(s);
run;
```

This will provide t values and degrees of freedom for equal and unequal variance assumptions between your two sample datasets, as well as the equivalent of a p-statistic showing the probability conversion of that t value (pr > |t|).   It also provides equality of variances statistics to help guide selection of equal/unequal variance stats, though always interpret such stats within the context of your existing domain knowledge and analytical design.

Proc ttest also offers paired design options - see the documentation here for more detail: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_ttest_sect006.htm